# how to implement WebGL blur on textureCube

Tags: glsl, webgl, shader

I know how to implement Gaussian blur with 2D coordinates when using texture2D.
But how do I blur when using textureCube which has 3D coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

A cube texture uses 3D coordinate as convenience but is actually a stored as 6 2D textures. So you can 2D blur individual faces and ideally cross sample faces to get proper blur between them. This will give a distorted result though.

To get a more even sampling, you should think of your cubemap as mapped onto a sphere. Then what you want to do is sample your kernel on the surface of the sphere. Basically, given your sampling direction, create a tangent space on the sphere in this direction and perform your kernel sampling in this tangent space.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder for the coord in `textureCube(sampler, coord)`, what would happen if points are not exactly on the surface? I now use built-in `reflect` to calc the points. Also, how can I get the 6 faces in GLSL side?